# Merge Request trigger for multibranch pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

How can you trigger a multi-branch pipeline on a merge request? The configurations do not save for specific branches in a multi-branch pipeline. And yes I do know that a single pipeline has an option to trigger on merge requests but I am looking for a solution for MULTI-BRANCH pipelines. I can't seem to find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use a combination of webhooks as well as the Jenkins Git service to trigger a multi-branch pipeline.

Your webhook url should look something like `<your-jenkins-url>/github-webhook`.